# Javascript Composite pattern, can not use overwritten methods correctly

Tags: javascript, iterator, this, composite

I have a javascript compositer pattern which i implemented (see code below).

In my main class i instantiate either the MenuItem or the Menu. I have to call the method `update()` on the component and they should return the corresponding code.

However it doesnt return the correct amount of `totalitems`. it alwasy returns the default value 0 which is defined in `MenuComponent`.

I think it has something to do with the `this` keyword but i can not find the exact solution.

**MenuItem:**

```
//MENU ITEM
//----------
var MenuItem = function(id) {
    MenuComponent.apply(this, [id, name]);
};

MenuItem.prototype = Object.create(MenuComponent.prototype);
MenuItem.prototype.constructor = MenuItem;

MenuItem.prototype.update = function() {
    //works
    console.log(this.ingredients)    
    //Doesnt work, this should display same as this.ingredients
    console.log(this.calculateIngredients())
    console.log("--------------")
};
```

**Menu:**

```
//MENU
//--------
var Menu = function(id, name) {
    MenuComponent.apply(this, [id, name]);
    this.menuitems = [];
};

Menu.prototype = Object.create(MenuComponent.prototype);
Menu.prototype.constructor = Menu;

Menu.prototype.add = function(menuitem) {
    this.menuitems.push(menuitem);
};
Menu.prototype.remove = function(menuitem) {
    for(var s, i = 0; s = this.getMenuItem(i); i++) {
        if(s == menuitem) {
            this.menuitems.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }

        if(s.remove(menuitem)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
Menu.prototype.getMenuItem = function(i) {
    return this.menuitems[i];
};
Menu.prototype.calculateIngredients = function() {
    this.ingredients = 0;
    for(var key in this.menuitems) {
        this.ingredients += this.menuitems[key].calculateIngredients();
    }
    return this.ingredients;
};
```

**MenuComponent**

```
//MenuComponent
//-------------
var MenuComponent = function(id, name) {

    if(this.constructor === MenuComponent) {
        throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract class");
    }

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = 0;
};

MenuComponent.prototype.calculateIngredients = function() {
    return this.ingredients;
};
MenuComponent.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log(this.ingredients)
    console.log("-----------------")
};
```

**example**

```
// HANDLER
var menuitem1 = new MenuItem(1)
    , menuitem2 = new MenuItem(2)
    , menuitem3 = new MenuItem(3)
    , menuitem4 = new MenuItem(4)
    , menuitem5 = new MenuItem(5)
    , menuitem6 = new MenuItem(6)
    , menuitem7 = new MenuItem(7)
    , menu = new Menu(1);

menu.add(menuitem1);
menu.add(menuitem2);
menu.add(menuitem3);
menu.add(menuitem4);

menuitem1.ingredients = 1
menuitem2.ingredients = 5
menuitem3.ingredients = 7;
menuitem4.ingredients = 2


// lets say i want to update the ingredient count of the following
menuitem1.update();
menuitem2.update();
menu.update();

//the update goes wrong, it doesnt display the correct amount, it alwasy displays 0 on the amounts where i commented
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp43N/)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle describing your problem?

Comment: I have updated my post with a better explanation of the code and adjusted some things to make it more understandable. i have also added a jsfiddle. Thank you for pointing this out to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
MenuComponent.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log(this.ingredients) // 0
};
```

You want to call

```
MenuComponent.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log(this.calculateIngredients()) // 15
};
```

whole code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/gjTb4/

Comment: Remove method `MenuComponent.prototype.calculateIngredients`

Comment: But then i have to implement it twice, 1 time in MenuItem and 1 time in Menu ?